# Why is this expression False?

Tags: python

In Python,

```py
1 in {1} == True
```

is `False` - why?

I first thought it's due to operator precedence, but all I can find (see below) tells me that the expression is evaluated from left to right:

- `1 in {1}` is `True`
- `True == True` is `True`

Also, any other precedence would lead to a `TypeError`:

- `{1} == True` is `False`
- `1 in False` returns a `TypeError`

---

> Python evaluates expressions from left to right.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order

Also,

> Operators in the same box have the same precedence. [...] Operators in the same box group left to right ([...]).
> [...]
> [image]

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: Note that "(1 in {1}) == True" is True. Something weird with order.

Comment: This is a good example of why you should almost never compare against `True`/`False` directly.  `1 in {1}` or `1 not in {1}` are sufficient.